# Rewrite <html> content

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I would like to rewrite the `<html>` content using Greasemonkey.

I tried this:

```
document.open()
document.write(html)
document.close()
```

Not working.

`document.body.innerHTML = html` only replaces the  content.

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write()`. It has all kinds of security restrictions (due to abuse by bad guys) and is [fraught with pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

if you try to use it, as in your question, in a userscript; Firefox will typically either stall the page completely or go into a perpetual `Connecting...` then reload cycle -- depending on when your script fires and whether you use `unsafeWindow.stop()`.
This kind of code still works in Chrome (for now), but remains a bad practice.  Not sure about other browsers.

The correct approach is to use DOM methods.  For example:

```
var D       = document;
var newDoc  = D.implementation.createHTMLDocument ("My new page title");
window.content = newDoc;

D.replaceChild (
    D.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    D.documentElement
);

D.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Standby...</h1>';
```

---

For enhanced performance, you may also wish to use:

```
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       unsafeWindow
```

and then place an `unsafeWindow.stop ();` at the top of the userscript code.

---

---

---

Re: `"How do I rewrite the head content with this solution?"`:

This example already rewrites the `<head>`.  The new head will be:

```
<head><title>My new page title</title></head>
```

in this case.

To add additional head elements, use DOM code like:

```
var newNode     = D.createElement ('base');
newNode.href    = "http://www.example.com/dir1/page.html";
var targ        = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0];
targ.appendChild (newNode);
```

**Except:**

1. Just use `GM_addStyle()` to easily create `<style>` nodes.
2. Adding `<script>` nodes is almost always pointless in your scenario.  Just have your userscript do any needed JS processing.
3. Some tags like `<meta>` will be added but not processed (especially in Firefox). Depending on the parameters, these are only parsed on initial load from a server.

Comment: How do I rewrite the head content with this solution ?

Comment: @mykiwi Just run the code. The HTML you want is in `D.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Standby...</h1>';`.